# Automated NDK testing, multiple APIs

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk, automated-tests

Android beginner here. I'm working on an NDK program written in C and I want to test it on Android APIs 15-30. What I'm looking for is a simple way to:

- Launch multiple AVD's as background processes (I don't need the phone popup)
- From my Linux terminal: adb push and execute my ELF onto these various devices all at once
  and get the prints/errors sent back to the Linux side

I'm open to any solutions using C, make, bash, python, or docker. I would like to use avd manager over Android Studio for this if possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, what's the specific problem that you have?

Comment: Start by doing it for 1 AVD and the generalize, then ask specific questions about those steps.